# mysql search value from nested json

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-json

I am trying to search userId for value 22  from nested json in mysql Column

my json is

```
 '{
     "data": [
            {"calendarId":"11","userId": "12"},
            {"calendarId":"21","userId": "22"}
           ]
    }'
```

I tried the following syntax :

```
1. where JSON_EXTRACT(column_field,'$.userId') = 22

2. where
JSON_EXTRACT(
column_field,
'$.data[*].userId'
) = 22
```

3. also tried with JSON_Table , but not getting exact nested json value in where condition.

Comment: MySQL or MariaDB ?

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to PHP?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
select json_extract('{
     "data": [
            {"calendarId":"11","userId": "12"},
            {"calendarId":"21","userId": "22"}
           ]
    }','$[0].data[*].userId');
```

gives:  `["12", "22"]`

and this:

```
select * 
from json_table(json_extract('{"data": [{"calendarId":"11","userId": "12"},{"calendarId":"21","userId": "22"}]}',
                '$[0].data[*].userId'), 
                '$[*]' columns (value int path "$")) x
;
```

gives:

| value |
| --- |
| 12 |
| 22 |

Adding a WHERE-clause, to just find the value `22` should not be a problem.

P.S. Above is tested using MySQL 8.x, see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/BqIdqlYX)

Comment: mine is 5.7 , json_table is giving err - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(json_extract('{"data": [{"calendarId":"11","userId": "12"},{"calendarId":"21","'

Comment: Indeed, see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/habyUlqa). Maybe you need to update your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that I tested with MySQL 5.7:

```
SELECT id, JSON_EXTRACT(data, REPLACE(path, '$', '$.data')) AS element
FROM (
  SELECT id, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data[*].userId'), 'one', '22')) AS path
  FROM mytable
) AS j
JOIN mytable USING (id);
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/Hvej9Ucd

If this seems too difficult or complex, then you should consider if JSON is the best way to store your data. This would be far simpler if you stored data in normal rows and columns, and avoided JSON.

This is what it might look like if you stored the data normally:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE userId = 22;
```